# Number puzzle - Next number in the sequence

Tags: number-sequence

I did a puzzle that made me calculate the last number, and I couldn't figure it out so I looked at the answer, but still don't understand how I get to that answer.

Number sequence is
`4 28 68 218 44 46 268`

And the following number (the answer) is:
`778`

How do I get to 778 using all the numbers?

Comment: What operations can we use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If we calculate the differences between a(n+1) - a(n), we get the following sequence:
>  24 40 150 -174 2 222
>  Googling this leads to an [another sequnce question on PSE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41413/number-sequence-puzzle-where-the-number-goes-down-in-the-middle). Now this one has multiple choise of answers but oddly enough the accepted solution referes to the answer being the only odd number. I guess in this case it will be the opposite - the answer might have been the only even number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that this is the most likely solution. I thought that the logic in a number sequence puzzle would lead to an answer, but in this case it seems there is only logic if you know the puzzle/answer combination.